# Why can we access private data members class using pointers, without using members friend function other members in the class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, pointers, private

As you know, private members can only be accessed by other members in the class

```
class DateClass // members are private by default
{
    int m_month; // private, can only be accessed by other members
    int m_day; // private, can only be accessed by other members
    int m_year; // private, can only be accessed by other members
};
 
int main()
{
    DateClass date;
    date.m_month = 12; // error
    date.m_day = 15; // error
    date.m_year = 2020; // error
 
    return 0;
}
```

But I was quite surprise that you can use pointers to access private data members. An example:

```
#include <iostream>  
  
class Test { 
private: 
    int data; 
  
public: 
    Test()
    {
        data = 0;
    }

    int getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}; 
  
int main() 
{ 
    Test t; 
    int* ptr = (int*)&t; 
    *ptr = 10; 
    std::cout << t.getData(); // it will return 10
    return 0; 
}
```

So is this intentional? Why private members can be accessed by pointers? I'm a beginner so this question is quite stupid.

Comment: You can generally access any memory address in the entire process. The idea of `private` is to limit your access **during compile time**, in order to protect yourself, as well as other **developers** using your code. Preventing read/write access is generally established on the HW level (MMU, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the behaviour of using the pointer obtained by the statement

```
int* ptr = (int*)&t;
```

is *undefined*. (Technically this is a *strict aliasing* violation).

C++ is littered with undefined constructs - which is one thing that makes the language fiendishly difficult to master. Given you're just setting out leaning C++ (there's no substitute for a good book by the way), avoid all casts until you know what you're doing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does class.mem/20 not apply in the OPs case, where the layout is standard an the first member is indeed `int`? I don't understand the sa-violation, and am genuinely curious.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Indeed this is a standard layout class (note all members have the same access) so the address of `t` is the same as the address of `data` within that `t`. But the types are still unrelated, so strict aliasing applies.

Comment: As I understand from [class.mem#general-note-12](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#general-note-12), the pointer are **interconvertible**, from [expr.static.cast#13](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#13), using `static_cast` from `void*` would be fine, so `int* ptr = static_cast<int*>(static_cast<void*>(&t))` would be fine. Alternatively, [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) should be fine too.